# bash Parse Command Line options

Tags: bash

Can some one tell me how to parse the following command line options with getopt?

```
myCmd [[-f <file> | -k | -v] -e <env> -h help]
```

where

`f`, `k` and `v` are mutually exclusive. `f` and `e` both need a parameter, but `k` and `v` do not.

So the command can be:

- mycmd -f file -e aaa or
- mycmd -v -e aaa or
- mycmd -k -e aaa

I have tried the following:

```
while getopts "f:kve:" o
    do
    case "$o" in
       f | k | v) process_file ;;
       k) process_key ;;
       v) process_var ;;
       e) process_env ;;
       *) print_help ;;
    esac
 done;
```

That does not seem to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with "*does not work*"? What behaviour do you expect?

Comment: I can not get f, k or v to be mutually exclusive

Answer (score 1):

You need to add that logic yourself. This is untested:

```
file=""
has_k=false
has_v=false
env=""

while getopts "f:kve:" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
        f) file="$OPTARG" ;;
        k) has_k=true ;;
        v) has_v=true ;;
        e) env="$OPTARG" ;;
        *) print_help; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))

if  ( [[ -n $file ]] && $has_k ) ||
    ( [[ -n $file ]] && $has_v ) ||
    ( $has_k && $has_v )
then
    echo "May only specify one of -f,-k,-v"
    print_help
    exit 1
fi
```